# How to install and configure Dynamic VLAN Server?

Tags: networking, webmin

I have below setup:

```
Firewall: Fortinet 240D
Core Switches are 2 one is Juniper EX 4200 & second one is EX 3300
```

I want to configure `Dynamic VLAN Server on Ubuntu Linux 12.04.3`

`Kernel and CPU:    Linux 3.8.0-32-generic on i686`

I have confirmed with Junniper technical support that EX3300 & EX4200 supports 802.1x Authentication.

Can anyone suggest which is the best software / package / or something like that I can install and get good/reliable documentation on installation/configuration and troubleshooting

Please suggest the best one as I do not have any specific in my mind but it would be great if it can be managed through some web portal that comes with it or can be managed from Webmin.

Comment: What is a "dynamic VLAN server" supposed to do?

Comment: @guntbert Hi! Dynamic VLAN Needs port based authentication to assign IP address. you can go through "Configuring 802.1X Port-Based Authentication" useing this link http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3550/software/release/12-1_13_ea1/configuration/guide/3550scg/Sw8021x.html